# Should I comment out these lines in the default rsnapshot configuration?

Tags: rsnapshot

I'm setting up the rsnapshot for backups. I've seen in the configuration file, the following backup lines are not commented by default. Should I leave them uncommented or not ?

I'm not interested in backing up my system, just specific folders.

```
backup  /home/          localhost/
backup  /etc/           localhost/
backup  /usr/local/     localhost/
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure which folder's you want, then yes, comment those lines out and add the specific folders you need.

The first folder will backup everything in the /home folder, including your data and any other user's data who has an account on your system.

The second will backup all your PC's "settings".

The last folder is for any local packages you've installed.

Remove them and replace them with specific folders to trim down the amount that you're backing up each iteration of rsnapshot.